# Computing the norm of $\hat{f_\epsilon(\xi)}=\chi_{[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]}(|\xi|).$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Given $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  For any $\epsilon \in(0,x)$, define $$\hat{f_\epsilon(\xi)}=\chi_{[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]}(|\xi|).$$ Where $\hat{f_\epsilon(\xi)}$ is the Fourier Transform $f$.

I am wondering how to compute the following:

1. $f$
2. $\|f\|$
3. $\|\hat{f}\|$
4. $\|\chi_{[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]}(|\xi|)\|$.

I know that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
% \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
  f(x) &=& 1/(2\pi)^n\int \hat{f_\epsilon(|\xi|)}e^{ix\xi}d\xi \\
   &=&1/(2\pi)^n\int \chi_{[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]}(|\xi|)e^{ix\xi}d\xi$\\
     &=&1/(2\pi)^n\int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon}e^{ix\xi}d\xi\\
     &=&1/(2\pi)^n\cdot 1/ix\cdot (e^{ix(x+\epsilon)}-e^{ix(x-\epsilon)}).   
\end{eqnarray*}

But this is not leading me to anything interesting!!

I also think that after obtaining $f$ I can go on and use $\|f\|_{L^2}=1/(2\pi)^{n/2}\|\hat{f}\|_{L^2}$ to obtain $\hat{f}$.  I need some help please.

Comment: Plancherel's Theorem should take care of the hard parts.

Comment: How can I use the Placherel's Theorem?  I need some ideas